# Is there a way to verify if celery is up in Google cloud as all the jobs are going to queue status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, celery, airflow

Is there a way to verify in Gcp if the celery is up or down as all our airflow jobs are going into queue status and not getting executed.  (airflow is running in google cloud)

[image]

Comment: For your requirement, you can check the [Airflow health status](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/logging-monitoring/check-health.html#). For understanding the reason of job getting stuck in queue and not executing, you can run airflow scheduler and airflow worker command. You can also monitor [Celery Executor metrics](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments#celery_executor_metrics) to check the status of the Celery Executor.

Comment: Did above comment help in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow has [flower built in](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/flower.html) which can be used to monitor celery:

> Flower is a web based tool for monitoring and administrating Celery clusters.